# Background Image won't show up in CSS unless I load an image using the <img> tag in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, facebook, background-image

I'm extremely confused why my code won't display the image properly. Here's my code:

```
<style type = "text/css">

#pic {

background:url('http://www.tishbi.eu/img/shopping_cart.png') no-repeat;


</style>

<div id = "pic"> <p>

</p> </div>
```

Only a tiny portion of the image is displayed along with the text... I'm so confused why this is happening. The only way I can display the whole image is if I add almost 170px of padding around the image. Someone please help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1. You need a closing brace before `</style>`
2. `#pic` has a width and height of zero, so the background wont show.  Either put content in the div, or set a width and height.

Check it out working, here: http://jsfiddle.net/UzcDM/1/

Comment: Thank you. I think I'm just overly tired. I can't believe I missed the bracket :\

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a width and height for your `div`.

Also, make sure you close your CSS:

```
#pic {
   background:url('http://www.tishbi.eu/img/shopping_cart.png') no-repeat;
   width: 200px;
   height: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put Height and width in your css class.

Please view **[demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Yx8tT/)** here

Comment: There is no such thing as a "css class", that is a rule set (which doesn't even have a class selector). Classes are an HTML concept, not a CSS one.

Answer (score 0):

taking that path set right e.g. ../../Images/logo/google.png,

try adding position:absolute;

it might be simply behind some elements