# Can't display PNG image as background of DIV

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm using a PNG image as background of a DIV:

```
background: url('/abc/pages/images/loading/loading_bg.png');
```

Display the DIV by setting CSS `display=block` but The image is not displayed.
The image exists and can be displayed by Chrome, if U type the full URL of the image in address bar.

If the image is displayed once, the background of DIV will be displayed OK.
This issue does not exist in IE or Firefox.
I changed the image to a `.JPG`, same issue exists.
I checked this image in resources tab (F12 in Chrome): the thumbnail is a broken file, but if I click "open image in new tab", it display correctly in the new tab!

Does anybody give me some tips about this? Thank you.

Supplement:
The "background-image" of the Computed Style is the URL of the image. So it's not override. This URL can be accessed by another tab, and the PNG image is displayed correctly in the new  tab. So there's no problem with the URL.
One more thing: when the page is displayed initially, the DIV is hidden by display:none . And I try to display it by display:block.
I post this on Chrome forum and no one answer it.

Comment: Do you have extension like AdBlock installed on your Chrome browser?

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633409/background-image-wont-show-up-in-css-unless-i-load-an-image-using-the-img-tag

Comment: I know it may sound silly but have you double checked the img src? Try to remove the '/' in front of abc/pages/...  Just a thought

Comment: Triple-check your URl, specifically, the file-path.

Comment: Also, are you sure that you're not overwriting your background-image later on in your styles?

Answer (score 1):

Background images won't affect the size of the element they are assigned to. If your `div` is empty, you need to set its `height` and `width` to match the size of your background image. Otherwise, an empty `div` has a `height` of 0 and won't be displayed.

Edit:

I confess, in my zeal to answer your question, I didn't read it fully, and my answer doesn't address your issue. I apologize.

Comment: The size of the div is not 0, checked by F12.

Answer (score 0):

If you want image not repeat, use **no-repeat** after the image path

If you want image repeat 'X' axis use **repeat-x** after the image path

If you want image repeat 'Y' axis use **repeat-y** after the image path

If you want image repeat 'X and Y' axis use **repeat** after the image path
eg:

background: url('/abc/pages/images/loading/loading_bg.png') no-repeat;

Comment: This bears no relevance to the question.